# apt dpkg error prevents GNOME Shell extension update

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, gnome-shell-extension, hplip

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I made the sudo install of gnome shell extensions but I still see that error message on the gnome extensions page:

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.

So I can not update my extensions. Could someone help please?

---

Here what I receive when I tried the proposition below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  chromium | chromium-browser firefox
The following NEW packages will be installed
  chrome-gnome-shell
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 23 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 13.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 73.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 chrome-gnome-shell all 10-1 [13.4 kB]
Fetched 13.4 kB in 0s (253 kB/s)              
Selecting previously unselected package chrome-gnome-shell.
(Reading database ... 227788 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chrome-gnome-shell_10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking chrome-gnome-shell (10-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3 (3.6.5-3ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py'
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                      Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                      No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                        dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any (>= 3.1~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chrome-gnome-shell:
 chrome-gnome-shell depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package chrome-gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager-core:
 update-manager-core depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 update-manager-core depends on python3-update-manager (= 1:18.04.11.3); however:
  Package python3-update-manager is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package update-manager-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-update-manager
 update-manager
 gnome-menus
 chrome-gnome-shell
 update-manager-core
 gconf2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: About hplip see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056876/66509).

Answer (score 3):

You have to install native connector

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Comment: I did that and it does not work but thank you for the answer anyway @cmak.fr