# Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, update-manager

I have been using ubuntu 18.04 for quite a while now and it was working fine until this morning when I turned my pc on and used terminal for updates.

This is the output of `sudo apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libuchardet0 lollypop-portal mpv phantomjs python3-bs4 python3-html5lib
  python3-lxml python3-pylast python3-pyxattr python3-webencodings rtmpdump
  youtube-dl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
26 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3 (3.6.5-3ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py'
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier-common:
 update-notifier-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of idle:
 idle depends on python3 (>= 3.6.5-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package idle (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.6.5-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan.io:
 netplan.io depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package netplan.io (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nplan:
 nplan depends on netplan.io; however:
  Package netplan.io is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nplan (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.192.1.3); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unattended-upgrades:
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of idle3:
 idle3 depends on python3 (>= 3.6.5-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 idle3 depends on idle (>= 3.6.5-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package idle is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package idle3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.
 update-manager depends on policykit-1-gnome | polkit-kde-agent-1 | lxpolkit | lxqt-policykit | mate-polkit | polkit-1-auth-agent; however:
  Package policykit-1-gnome is not installed.
  Package polkit-kde-agent-1 is not installed.
  Package lxpolkit is not installed.
  Package lxqt-policykit is not installed.
  Package mate-polkit is not installed.
  Package polkit-1-auth-agent is not installed.
  Package gnome-shell which provides polkit-1-auth-agent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any (>= 3.1~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager-core:
 update-manager-core depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 update-manager-core depends on python3-update-manager (= 1:18.04.11.3); however:
  Package python3-update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 update-notifier-common
 idle
 python3-update-manager
 python3-dev
 gnome-shell
 netplan.io
 nplan
 update-notifier
 unattended-upgrades
 idle3
 update-manager
 gnome-menus
 update-manager-core
 gconf2
 gdm3
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I found [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056746/apt-error-when-installing-o-upgrading-packages), but i can't comment on that without asking a question myself so here is my problem. help would be appreciated. I also ran `apt-cache policy hplip` as was asked in the other post and got the same result.

```
]hplip:
  Installed: 3.17.10+repack0-5
  Candidate: 3.17.10+repack0-5
  Version table:
 *** 3.17.10+repack0-5 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: How did you installed HPLIP?

Comment: @N0rbert I installed it from HP's official website here: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

Actually I installed it a few days ago

Comment: Which guide did you use? Usually deb-packaged and binary-versions are in confliсt. So you should remove hplip deb-packages before you install binary-version.

Comment: @N0rbert I downloaded the .run file from the Sourceforge link that it provided So it was the binary version. I don't think i had the deb package already installed before i installed the binary version.

Comment: It seems that you should remove broken `hplip-data` package with `sudo apt-get purge hplip-data`.

Comment: `APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (90 vs 94). Affected packages: python3:amd64`

@N0rbert I have purged the data, would this affect hplip in any way? Why was this package left in the first place?

I have had problem with hp's printing service in linux since i was using Ubuntu 14. They can't seem to get it work properly

Comment: I think that the problem is HPLIP installer. It incorrectly uninstalls Ubuntu-packaged version by deleting files, which are maintained by package manager. I'm currently updating [my guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) to reflect the situation. I'll check it again and inform you when complete.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks, that worked perfectly. can you answer the question so that others can also solve this issue. I have seen three similar posts that were asked just a couple of days ago, also the question that i linked most probably have same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually deb-packaged and binary-versions are in conflict. 
So you should remove `hplip`-related deb-packages before you install binary-version.

The problem is HPLIP installer. It incorrectly uninstalls Ubuntu-packaged version by deleting files, which are maintained by package manager.

They have note about this problem on [support page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/step3/index):

> Warning: If you are upgrading HPLIP and HPLIP is already preinstalled with your distribution, or you if you installed HPLIP using an RPM, DEB, or other package, please uninstall the previous version using the method specific for your distribution. If you do not do this, you may have package conflict issues or functionality problems.

It would be safer to reinstall binary HPLIP again by following the guide in my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509).

Comment: Your other answer is very useful, so thanks for that. With that said, the other answer states what to do when starting from a functional system. If you have already "broken" the package manager as per this question, what steps should you carry out to end up in the position you would be if you had followed the other answer in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

This is problem of HPLIP driver. Download it from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing. The error itself says it is expecting `/usr/share/hplip/ui5/*` . So please install the library in that folder or install somewhere else and move to the specified folder.