# Errors after sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: 18.04

I had a problem on 18.04. It seems the system never updated since I installed it in March, because of a Heroku "failing" package/repo. (sorry for wrong wording but I am new to Ubuntu)

Now my system has fully updated (Firefox, Thunderbird ..) and Software and updates are up-to-date.

Also my system seems stable and everything seems to work.

However, `sudo apt-get -f install` gives the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
41 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3 (3.6.5-3ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py'
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier-common:
 update-notifier-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-commandnotfound:
 python3-commandnotfound depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-commandnotfound (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pyqt5:
 python3-pyqt5 depends on python3 (<< 3.7); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-pyqt5 depends on python3 (>= 3.6~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-pyqt5 depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pyqt5 (--configNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                               No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                           ure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-common:
 language-selector-common depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-xdg:
 python3-xdg depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-xdg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                       depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan.io:
 netplan.io depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package netplan.io (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of command-not-found:
 command-not-found depends on python3-commandnotfound (= 18.04.5); however:
  Package python3-commandnotfound is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package command-not-found (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apport:
 python3-apport depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-terminal:
 gnome-terminal depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-terminal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-session:
 ubuntu-session depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.24.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-session (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-problem-report:
 python3-problem-report depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-problem-report (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-gtk depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nplan:
 nplan depends on netplan.io; however:
  Package netplan.io is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nplan (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.192.1.3); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-software:
 gnome-software depends on software-properties-gtk; however:
  Package software-properties-gtk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-software (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unattended-upgrades:
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport:
 apport depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 apport depends on python3-apport (>= 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2); however:
  Package python3-apport is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.
 update-manager depends on policykit-1-gnome | polkit-kde-agent-1 | lxpolkit | lxqt-policykit | mate-polkit | polkit-1-auth-agent; however:
  Package policykit-1-gnome is not installed.
  Package polkit-kde-agent-1 is not installed.
  Package lxpolkit is not installed.
  Package lxqt-policykit is not installed.
  Package mate-polkit is not installed.
  Package polkit-1-auth-agent is not installed.
  Package gnome-shell which provides polkit-1-auth-agent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-software-properties:
 python3-software-properties depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any (>= 3.1~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.188.1); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.
 language-selector-gnome depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
 flashplugin-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5:
 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 depends on python3 (<< 3.7); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 depends on python3 (>= 3.6~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 depends on python3:any (>= 3.3~); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-louis:
 python3-louis depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-louis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of networkd-dispatcher:
 networkd-dispatcher depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package networkd-dispatcher (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3-update-manager (>= 1:0.196.2~); however:
  Package python3-update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3-software-properties (= 0.96.24.32.4); however:
  Package python3-software-properties is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cryptography:
 python3-cryptography depends on python3 (>= 3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cryptography depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal:
 nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal depends on gnome-terminal (= 3.28.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.1); however:
  Package gnome-terminal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-speechd:
 python3-speechd depends on python3-xdg; however:
  Package python3-xdg is not configured yet.
 python3-speechd depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-speechd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for ufw:
 ufw depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ufw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:18.04.21); however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:18.04.21); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager-core:
 update-manager-core depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 update-manager-core depends on python3-update-manager (= 1:18.04.11.4); however:
  Package python3-update-manager is not configured yet.
 update-manager-core depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (>= 1:18.04.9); however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-software:
 ubuntu-software depends on gnome-software (>= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1); however:
  Package gnome-software is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-software (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apt:
 python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.7); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.6~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-software-plugin-snap:
 gnome-software-plugin-snap depends on gnome-software (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1); however:
  Package gnome-software is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-software-plugin-snap (--configureNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                    ):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on language-selector-gnome (>= 0.179~); however:
  Package language-selector-gnome is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 update-notifier-common
 python3-commandnotfound
 python3-pyqt5
 language-selector-common
 python3-xdg
 python3-update-manager
 gnome-shell
 apport-gtk
 netplan.io
 command-not-found
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 python3-apport
 gnome-terminal
 ubuntu-session
 python3-problem-report
 software-properties-gtk
 nplan
 update-notifier
 gnome-software
 unattended-upgrades
 apport
 update-manager
 python3-software-properties
 gnome-menus
 language-selector-gnome
 flashplugin-installer
 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
 python3-louis
 networkd-dispatcher
 python3-distupgrade
 software-properties-common
 python3-cryptography
 nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
 python3-speechd
 ufw
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 update-manager-core
 ubuntu-software
 python3-apt
 gnome-software-plugin-snap
 gdm3
 gnome-control-center
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: Follow uninstallation procedure [from duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509). Then consider which version of HPLIP you plan to use and follow installation part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a script hasn't installed a dependency.

[By searching the Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=hplip&mode=filename&suite=bionic&arch=any), it appears that the `/usr/share/hplip` folder is created by the `hplip-data` package.

I'd suggest trying to install this package directly.  `apt install hplip-data` and try again.

Comment: thanks. I just tried this but the exact above errors show up when I `sudo apt install hplip-data` hplip is for my HP printer and I remember having installed it manually by downloading the file then `sh` it if I remember well.

Comment: I followed this tut : https://www.wikihow.com/Install-HPLIP-to-Linux Maybe installing a newer version would fix ? One newer version does exist

Comment: Thnaks for directing me to hplilp, my question is actually a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056780/cant-upgrade-update-ubuntu-18-04-as-apt-dpkg-error-is-showing-up and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner#1056078 Problem getting solved soon ! (hopefully)