# QGIS not installing in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, dpkg, dependencies, qgis

**When I install QGIS-ltr version in ubuntu 22.04, the following error pops out and I have tried every solution previously given but of no use.**

Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.34.3+36jammy) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libpdal_util.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.34.3+36jammy); however:
Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:3.34.3+36jammy); however:
Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-qgis:
python3-qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.34.3+36jammy); however:
Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-qgis (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
qgis-providers
qgis
qgis-plugin-grass
python3-qgis
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 1):

[Override the version conflict:](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/52433#issuecomment-1792285094):

1. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpdal_base.so.15 /usr/lib/libpdal_base.so.13`
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpdal_util.so.15 /usr/lib/libpdal_util.so.13`
3. `sudo ldconfig`
4. Retry your installation

Comment: This answer is similar to https://askubuntu.com/a/1056876/, but I am inclined to give you the benefit of the doubt and reopen this question if your answer becomes the accepted answer to this question.Please inform me in a comment if this happens.

Comment: @karel Did you paste the wrong link? My answer only uses "ln" and "ldconfig". Your link and the duplicates only use "apt" and "dpkg". Where is the similarity?

Comment: There is no similarity is why I'm going to reopen this question if your answer is accepted, so I don't waste an accepted answer.

Comment: This answer works for me.